# Is it possible to simulate page requests in Rails using rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, mongodb, heroku, redis

I've been working on a rails project that's unusual for me in a sense that it's not going to be using a MySQL database and instead will roll with mongoDB + Redis.

The app is pretty simple - "boot up" data from mongoDB to Redis, after which point rails will be ready to take requests from users which will consist mainly of pulling data from redis, (I was told it'd be pretty darn fast at this) doing a quick calculation and sending some of the data back out to the user.
This will be happening ~1500-4500 times per second, with any luck.

Before the might of the user army comes down on the server, I was wondering if there was a way to "simulate" the page requests somehow internally - like running a rake task to simply execute that page N times per second or something of the sort?

If not, is there a way to test that load and then time the requests to get a rough idea of the delay most users will be looking at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Caveat

Performance testing is a very broad topic, and the right tool often depends on the type and quality of results that you need. As just one example of the issues you have to deal with, consider what happens if you write a benchmark spec for a specific controller action, and call that method 1000 times in a row. This might give a good idea of performance of that controller method, but it might be making the same redis or mongo query 1000 times, the results of which the database driver may be caching. This also ignores the time it'll take your web server to respond and serve up the static assets that are part of the request (this may be okay, especially if you have other tests for this).

## Basic Tools

- **`ab`, or ApacheBench,** is a simple commandline tool that you can use to test the throughput and speed of your app. I usually go to this first when I want to send a thousand requests at a web server, or test how many simultaneous requests my app can handle (e.g. when comparing mongrel, unicorn, thin, and goliath). Because all requests originate from the same server, this is good for a small number of requests, but as the number of requests grow, you'll be limited by the resources on your testing machine (network stack, cpu, and maybe memory).
- [**Benchmark** is a standard ruby class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html), and is great for quickly spitting out some profiling information. It can also be used with [Test::Unit](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html) and [RSpec](https://github.com/michaeledgar/rspec-benchmark). If you want a rake task for doing some quick benchmarking, this is probably the place to start
- **`mechanize`** - I like using [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) for quickly scripting an interaction with a page. It handles cookies and forms, but won't go and grab assets like images by default. It can be a good tool if you're rolling your own tests, but shouldn't be the first one to go to.
- There are also some tools that will simulate actual users interacting with the site (they'll download assets as a browser would, and can be configured to simulate several different users). Most notable are [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) and [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/). While still very much in development, I'm currently working on [tsung-rails](https://github.com/btaitelb/tsung-rails) to make it easier to automate rails load testing with tsung, and would love some help if you choose to go in this direction :)

## Rails Profiling Links

- [Good overview for writing performance tests](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html)
- [Great slide deck covering most of the latest tools for profiling at various levels](https://speakerdeck.com/u/tmm1/p/debugging-ruby-performance)

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you. To clarify a little bit - there will be no static resources or even html pages to return. The *one* page in question will receive a small JSON, (under a kb) fetch a hash from redis (2-5kb tops), then send back another JSON that's about 3kb~ in size. So I don't think caching will be an issue. Based on that, which approach from the ones you've listed do you recommend I try?

Comment: I'd recommend benchmarking the controller method itself, and then verifying your results using ab. If there's a discrepancy, then investigate why. Btw, if performance is a concern, and you don't need the full rails and rack stacks, then I highly recommend checking out goliath.

Comment: Thanks. From reading some stuff about how heroku handles scaling it seems now that I need to have two applications - one a rails app to deal with just a handful of users and something like goliath to provide the api functionality very quickly. Is there a way to co-house both rails and goliath on heroku? I imagine it's unlikely

Comment: You can do this via your Procfile, where you have a web server running rails, and an api server running goliath that fields requests from rails. You can then scale them separately, and it's a pretty nice setup, but you'll have to pay for each instance.